# How to update another components content based on navigation events?

Tags: angular

I know that components in Angular [can interact](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) in certain ways. Using e.g. the `@Input` decorator.

However, what I do not quite get is how I could update a component based on navigation events.

In particular I am talking about a header which is supposed to change. For example in `/home` it should be empty, in `/group?id=1` it should show the group name but also display some buttons etc.

Since the application does have a certain layout:

```
<div class="header-container">
  <app-header>
    <!-- Individual header content goes here -->
  </app-header>
</div>

<div class="content-container" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
  <app-content fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
  </app-content>
</div>

<div class="footer-container">
</div>
```

I was wondering what is the way to go to update `<app-header/>` individually?

Comment: Do you want the routed components to dictate the header content?

Comment: One approach would be to use a BehaviorSubject that the routed components update, and the app-header component subscribes to.

Comment: @TomaszKula Yes, I think so. E.g. in `/groups?id=1` there could be a home button on top, but as I click on *settings* within that group, this sub-location might again change the header and just show a *return* button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [presentation](https://youtu.be/rKbY1t39dHU?t=1m33s) done by Alex Rickabaugh (Angular Core) on how to create a SideNav with content dictated by the routed components.

The full implementation is a bit complex,  as it combines listening to therouter events and creating a custom structural directive, but it is well worth a look. You will learn a lot by going through the code.

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <left-nav></left-nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

**a.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
<h2>I am Route A</h2>

<div *leftNav>
  <h3>Route A Nav</h3>
</div>
`
})
export class RouteA {}
```

**b.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
<h2>I am Route B</h2>

<div *leftNav>
  <h3>Route B Nav</h3>
</div>
`
})
export class RouteB {}
```

[Full implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav)

All the credit goes to Alex, I'm just presenting his solution.